# Silverlight 3; switching to culture zh-Hans throws exception

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, localization

I'm trying to localize my Silverlight 3.0 app to Simplified Chinese.

However, when I attempt to switch to that culture (zh-Hans, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.95%29.aspx)
with this code:

```
var currentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-Hans");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
```

I get the following exception:

```
Culture name 'zh-Hans' is not supported.
```

I'm using Windows XP SP3 on an en-GB machine.

Is this a problem with Silverlight 3?  Or do I need to install some extra Windows XP language packs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that my installation of Windows XP (default en-GB) didn't have the files for East Asian languages installed by default.

Enabling these was quite simple - see 
http://newton.uor.edu/Departments&Programs/AsianStudiesDept/Language/asianlanguageinstallation_XP.html for instructions.

After I'd done that, I was able to change Silverlight 3.0 to zn-Hans and zn-SG

```
var currentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-Hans");
```

or

```
var currentCulture = new CultureInfo("zh-SG");
```

etc.

Comment: The link no longer works - could you please detail the steps directly in your answer?